# golang closure(anonymous function)catch wrong parameter`s value

Tags: function, go, closures, anonymous

see test code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 10

    closure1 := func() {
        fmt.Printf("closure, i: %d\n", i)
        i = 15
    }

    closure1()

    fmt.Printf("in main, i: %d\n", i)

    closure2 := func(x int) {
        fmt.Printf("function call, pass parameter, i: %d\n", x)
    }

    i = 20

    closure1()
    closure2(i)
}
```

I think the output of the closure2 should be 20, but the real result is 15, i do not know why????
anybody can help me , please see my comment in my code, thanks in advance.

Comment: `i` is assigned 15 at the end of `closure1`, which you call before your call to `closure2`. So you pass 15 to `closure2`

Comment: [Pitfalls With Closures In Go](http://www.goinggo.net/2014/06/pitfalls-with-closures-in-go.html)

Comment: i see, golang closure catch a reference to i, not a snapshot value, i get it , thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your first assigning i to 15 when your calling `closure1()` And then closure two you print it.. Your doing `closure1()` **after** assigning i to 20.. Thats the problem, this should fix your problem:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := 10

    closure1 := func() {
        fmt.Printf("closure, i: %d\n", i)
        i = 15
    }

    closure1()

    fmt.Printf("in main, i: %d\n", i)

    closure2 := func(x int) {
        fmt.Printf("function call, pass parameter, i: %d\n", x)
    }



    closure1()
    i = 20 // Now it assigns it back to 20.. So the result below will become 20...
    closure2(i)
}
```

You see your problem?

Comment: yes , in essence ,  golang closure catch a reference to i, not a snapshot value, i get it , thank you john and dsafds again, by the way , " 
Pitfalls With Closures In Go" is good learning material.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of closure1 sets i to 15.  This i belongs to the main() context.

The next to last line of main calls closure1() again.  So the i from main is set to 15 again.